# mapping values are not allowed in this context salt stack

Tags: yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

Not able to assign variable under for loop in salt stack

```
{% set prli = ['httpd','rhnsd'] %}
{% for usr in prli %}
{% set pro = salt['cmd.shell'](' ps -eaf | grep -i {{ usr }} | wc -l') %}
{{ usr }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "{{ usr }} {{ pro }}"
{% endfor %}
```

~

getting error

### Data failed to compile:

```
Rendering SLS 'failed: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% set prli = ['httpd','rhnsd'] %}
{% for usr in prli %}
{% set pro = salt['cmd.shell']('ps -eaf | grep -i' ~ usr ~ '| wc -l') %}
{{ usr }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "{{ usr }} {{ pro }}"
{% endfor %}
```

You can't use `{{ }}` inside a jinja statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i  am facing below issue

Comment: {% set prli = ['httpd','rhnsd'] %}
{% for usr in prli %}
{% set pro = salt['cmd.shell'](' ps -eaf | grep -i  '~ usr ~'  | grep -iv grep|wc -l') %}
{% if pro|int > 0 %}:
checkimg:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "{{ usr }} {{ pro }}"
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
                                                                                                                                                                       getting below error  failed: while parsing a block mapping
did not find expected key
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1

Comment: Can Any one please me on above query

Comment: The formatting is not very good. But I can see a **:** behind "{% if pro|int > 0 %}"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue came down to the additional `:`(colon) in the salt state file

eg:

```
cmd.run:
  - name: foo
  - onchanges:
    - file: bar: <-- this colon is the root cause
```

Comment: I got the same error because I was MISSING a ":" after an entry.  Sigh.